# Why is my function returning garbage when it should return a char?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

I'm a newbie in C++ learning the language and playing around. I wrote a piece of code which behavior I don't understand. Could someone explain why the code below prints out random junk and not the first character of the first string in the list (that is `a`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <climits>
#include <stdio.h>


char* str2char(std::string str)
{
    char cset[str.size()+1]; // +1 for the null character
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        cset[i] = str[i];
    }
    cset[str.size()] = '\0';
    return cset;
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {



    std::vector< std::string > ladontakadet;
    ladontakadet.push_back("aabcbbca");
    ladontakadet.push_back("abcdabcd");
    ladontakadet.push_back("cbbdcdaa");
    ladontakadet.push_back("aadcbdca");
    ladontakadet.push_back("cccbaaab");
    ladontakadet.push_back("dabccbaa");
    ladontakadet.push_back("ccbdcbad");
    ladontakadet.push_back("bdcbccad");
    ladontakadet.push_back("ddcadccb");
    ladontakadet.push_back("baccddaa");

    std::string v = ladontakadet.at(0);
    char *r;
    r = str2char(v);
    std::cout << r[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is my returning garbage, when I'm expecting it to output `a`?

Thnx for any help!

P.S. The output of this code is random. It doesn't always print the same character..:S

Comment: In the future please don't post screenshots of code, it's makes it impossible to copy the code.

Comment: A simple formatted code would do, an image is an overkill here.

Comment: +1 Okay, sorry about that

Comment: It will not compile (unless in C++14) and it is undefined behavior to return the local cset

Comment: @DieterLücking I updated the code. That should compile :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to pass the content of a std::string to a function modifying the content of a char*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void f(char* s) {
    s[0] = 'H';
}

std::vector<char> to_vector(const std::string& s) {
    return std::vector<char>(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.size() + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string s = "_ello";
    std::vector<char> t = to_vector(s);
    f(t.data());
    std::cout <<  t.data() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It's because you return a pointer to a local variable, a local variable that goes out of scope when the function returns.

You are already using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for the argument, use it instead of the array and the return pointer.

Comment: +1 Thnx for your help...I've been thinking that myself (using string instead) :( But my problem is that I'm using a piece of code someone else has written and I don't want to go and change it (because it's kinda long), so I have to use char arrays x(

Comment: And variable length arrays are not legal in the first place.

Comment: @jjepsuomi, you can always fall back and use `string.c_str()` to retrieve the C-string.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is returning garbage because you're returning the address of a local variable which goes out of scope after your function returns. It should probably look like this:

```
char* str2char(const std::string &str)
{
    char *const cset = new char[str.size() + 1]; // +1 for the null character
    strcpy(cset, str.c_str());
    return cset;
}
```

You will need to delete your variable `r` by doing `delete[] r;`. Ideally though you wouldn't be using raw pointers, and you would use `std::string` for everything, or wrap the `char *` in a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @MarkIngram could you explain a bit more. I didn't fully understand the phrase "address of a local variable which goes out of scope after your function returns" =) Why does it go out of scope? :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi You create your variable `cset` on the stack (vs the heap, which is what my example does). At the end of scope, in this case, the function (basically the `{ }` brackets), means that the stack is popped and all variables destroyed, meaning your `cset` variable is destroyed. Then you return your destroyed variable, which means it's now pointing to garbage.